# Function import with EF and Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, silverlight, stored-procedures

When trying to import a stored procedure from Oracle 10g into Entity Framework 4, I get the following error:

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Here are some details:

- The stored procedure executes successfully if I run it directly from the database.
- The stored procedure is set up to return 0 records if all `null`s are passed in (but it still contains column information).
- My TNS Names files **is** set up correctly, I can connect via other tools such as LINQpad or PL/SQL with my TNS identifier to this database, so my TNS Names file is not the problem.

If it matters, the project that this EF model is associated with is Silverlight 5.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, if you have your Entity Framework model inside a class library (dll), even though your connection strings belong in the app.config/web.config of your main applicaiton, EF will use the connection string(s) provided in the app.config **of the class library itself**. So make sure your connection strings in the app.config in the project where your edmx models are, are correct.